# Blues harmonica to start

Tags: harmonica, beginner

I want to start harmonica. I got some advice from a teacher who told me : "if you want to start harmonica you should start with Tremolo harmonica". But honestly I love blues harmonica.

is it right if I want to play blues harmonica the best way is to start with tremolo or I can start with Blues harmonica instantly ?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Wiki article for tremolo claims it's the most popular style, especially in Europe and Asia.  Yet when I was researching harmonicas last year, most of the discussion I saw was for 10 hole diatonics, with chromatics a distant second.

On https://www.harptabs.com/ there are many more contributions for the diatonic than the tremolo.  Most of the tremolo tabs are from one poster.

http://www.harmonicaacademy.com/categories/20101027

> The tremolo harmonica is different. No bending is required. In fact, bending is difficult with the double reeds, and rarely done.
>
> The tremolo is therefore easier for tunes than the 10 hole, because note bending is not needed. All the notes are there. The tremolo is not so good for blues, as note bending is a big part of the blues harmonica sound.

Bending, if I recall correctly, was developed by blues players to produce notes that aren't normally played on the 20 reeds.

The first challenge for a beginning player is to blow or draw one note at a time.  With a wider separation, that is probably easier on the tremolo.  Bending is a more advanced skill, but essential to a blues sound.

Answer (score 2):

I started on blues harp and never really went much past it. Not to say I didn't spend a lot of time learning and practicing harmonica. There's lots to be learned on the humble blues harp!

I really don't know why a tremolo harmonica would be any easier, but I've never played one.

If music is meant to be fun, then you'd better go for and fight for the thing you want to do because you think it will be fun.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to start to play harmonica for blues, you must use a diatonic harmonica, specially in the key of C.

The key of C is used to start to play harmonica because this key is in mid-octave range, not too low tune and not too high tune.

To start to play harmonica, I recommend you use a hohner special 20...

Comment: False. You don't have to have a diatonic harp to play blues (although I agree that it helps a lot) and you **definitely** don't have to start in the key of C. I'm pretty sure my first blues harp was in G, and then I picked up a Bb harp. In fact, of my five blues harps I'm pretty sure *none* are in the key of C.

Comment: I've seen a seems-to-know-his-stuff guy on YouTube say that for blues you need a harmonica that's offset 4 steps from the rythm - e.g. for a blues in G, you'll want t harp in C. If the blues rythm is in another key your C harp will sound off. If you're playing by yourself / on your own, the key makes no difference.