# Advice for first harmonica

Tags: learning, harmonica

Please tell me: for a beginner, which type of harmonica I should buy? Without knowing I have bought a Walther Harmonica, and both side has 48 holes. One side has a written C, and the other side G.

Can I practice with this Harmonica? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend starting with a more beginner-friendly harmonica (that is, with fewer holes) for now, just to get the basics down. I've always heard great things about the Hohner 20, but of course everyone will have different opinions on where to start.

Starting with a harmonica like the Hohner 20 has multiple advantages, but the two biggest ones (as I see it) are:

1. A wealth of learning material designed explicitly for someone starting on an instrument like this.
2. The ability to play actual music much more quickly. In other words, it'll be more fun, and sooner!

With that said, you can certainly keep the Walther; you can come back to it once you've mastered the basics on a more beginner-appropriate instrument.

Of course, you're welcome to just "jump right in" and start learning on the Walther, but the process will probably take a little longer. It will also probably be difficult to find learning materials for that harmonica, since most material will assume an understanding of the basics learned on something like a Hohner 20.

Answer (score 2):

I found references to a Walther Chromatic 48.  Does yours have a button or slide on the side that changes pitch of the notes?  It should make every note `sharper`.

If so, then any instruction for a chromatic harmonica should work.  I believe the note layout is the same for every chromatic; they just differ in how many octaves they cover.

Or maybe it's a tremolo; I found a Swan 'Double sided C/G 48 hole tremolo harmonica'.  Americans don't know much about tremolo harmonicas.  They mostly play 10 hole diatonics.  But tremolo is more popular in Asia.

[Blues harmonica to start](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/38882/23218)

There are few other questions about tremolo harmonicas.